# SQL - How do I find the exact string in a list of strings that can be part of another string in the list?

Tags: sql, string, oracle, delimiter, sql-like

The question sounds confusing but I have a column of data that is divided up by characters `|~*~|`. I am trying to find data based on the strings in between these characters. The line of characters doesn't start with the delimiter but it does end with it.

e.g. `Product Developer|~*~|Technician|~*~|`

The issue I've run into is the following:

```
Product Developer|~*~|Technician|~*~|Lead Product Developer|~*~|
```

If I search for `WHERE T.COLUMN LIKE '%Lead Product Developer%'` it is fine I get that column, but if I search for `WHERE T.COLUMN LIKE '%Product Developer%'` then I'll get where `Lead Product Developer` and `Product Developer` since it is part of the string. How can I avoid this and only get exactly the string I am looking for.

Here is a snippet of what I have:

`SELECT 
    T.COLUMN,
  FROM TABLE1 T
  WHERE T.COLUMN LIKE '%Product Developer%'`

Comment: You have a lousy data structure.

Comment: Not to pile on, but this is a horrible design. While I'm sure you will get many creative solutions to your problem, you are really not using the product they way it was designed to be used. You will run into more problems down the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your data structure is wrong, wrong, wrong.  The correct *SQL* way of representing this relationship is with another table, with one row per whatever and item in the list.  In addition, Oracle offers JSON structures and nested tables.  So, there is no shortage of ways to do this right.

Sometimes, we are stuck with other people's really bad design decisions.  In this case, you can use `like` in a clever way:

```
WHERE '|~*~|' || T.COLUMN LIKE '%|~*~|Product Developer|~*~|%'
```

Because `column` ends with a delimiter, you don't need to add it to the end again, only to the beginning.

Comment: Yeah, the design is atrocious but like you said we are stuck with others work. I'm just building a query to get very high-level analytics on stuff, so I'm not too worried about how sloppy the SQL looks. I'll give your answer a shot. Thanks!